# Haskell -- Understanding the writer type declaration

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming, monads, record

I am learning about monads in the book 'Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!' by Miran Lipovaca. I am reading about how the Control.Monad.Writer module exports the `Writer w a type` along with its Monad instance and some useful functions for dealing with values of this type.

It gives a `Writer type` declaration example.

For the following code:

```haskell
-- Writer w a corresponding to (a, w)  <--- the order is reversed
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) } -- <--- (a, w)
```

Here, why is the pair type order reversed?

Can I make the declaration of `Writer type` like this?

```haskell
-- Writer w a corresponding to (w, a) <--- same order with Writer w a
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (w, a) } -- <--- (w, a)
```

If I took the second choice of `Writer type` declaration, Is there anything bad influence in writing Haskell?

In order to find out `Writer Monad`, I have tried reading `Haskell Writer Monad Source Code`
(From https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict.html#WriterT)

```haskell
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (a, w) }
```

The pair type order is also reversed. Why can't define it like this?

```haskell
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (w, a) }
```

Is there any reason for this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

As evidenced by the [swap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v:swap) function, a tuple `(a, b)` is isomorphic to `(b, a)`, so yes, you can trivially change the order of the elements of the tuple. It makes no difference in capability.

There are often historical reasons why certain APIs look as they do. I'm not aware of the exact history behind the Writer monad, but in general, if you imagine that you're coming from an imperative/procedural/object-oriented background, an API equivalent to something Writer-based would be a procedure that returns a value but also changes some mutable state (a global variable, or a mutable input argument).

In C#, for example, it might look like this:

```
public int Foo(ICollection<string> log)
```

where the return value is an `int`, while the writable resource is a collection of strings.

Once you decide to get rid of mutation, you have to instead return a new version of the `log`, but since the method already returns an `int`, you'll have to return a tuple. Should you make the 'original' return type the first or the second element in the tuple?

It seems intuitive to make the 'original' return type the first element. Thus, in the above example, you may instead have an API like this (now in Haskell syntax):

```
foo :: [String] -> (Int, [String])
```

or, more generally,

```
(a, w)
```

When it comes to types that have `Functor` and `Monad` instances, however, Haskell requires that the type variable that is 'engaged' in `fmap`, `>>=`, etcetera is the rightmost type variable.

That's the reason that `WriterT w m a` is defined with the `a` farthest to the right, instead of, say, `WriterT w a m` or `WriterT a w m`.

Given that the `a` must be farthest to the right, a follow-up question might be: *Why is it `WriterT w m a` instead of `WriterT m w a`?*

That's because by putting the 'monad' type variable `m` to the right of the Writer type variable `w`, you can partially apply the `Identity` monad to `WriterT` to define `Writer`:

```
type Writer w = WriterT w Identity
```

It may be a good exercise to see if you can swap `(a, w)` with `(w, a)` and see if you can still implement all the instances.

Comment: If defined the other way, `runWriter (fmap f x)` would be the same as `fmap f (runWriter x)`. Is that a desirable symmetry, or is it "wasting" API space compared to letting you say two different things concisely? I agree it's pretty arbitrary, and what they picked didn't matter much.

Comment: "That's because by putting the 'monad' type variable `m` to the right of the `Writer` type variable `w`, you can partially apply the Identity monad to `WriterT` to define `Writer`:" This seems wrong; if it were `WriterT m w a` then `type Writer = Writer Identity` seems even better. I would say the actual reason is because `WriterT w m a` makes `WriterT w` a monad transformer, while `Writer m w a` leaves you without a way to name that transformer.

Comment: `(w, a)` may be even considered more natural, since it leveragies the `Functor` instance for pairs, and if the module had been written today I suspect that would be the order (we have learned a thing or two about how types compose over the years)